# Troubleshooting conflicting elements on a website

Tags: javascript, slick.js, swiper.js

I am working on a website and there seems to be conflicting elements.

I started with [a template](https://www.templatemonsterpreview.com/demo/58975.html) that contains a lot of "borrowed" CSS and JS elements from different places, and now I am trying to add a **[Slick slideshow](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)**, and there are conflicts in either the JS or the CSS that prevent me from editing the Slick slider (parts of the slick-slider code were already present in the "Organic Farm" template).

Right now I have `js/core.min.js`, `js/script.js` and `js/slick.js` being loaded into the page, and then at the bottom of the index page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.swiper-slide').slick({
          dots: true,
          infinite: true,
          speed: 300,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          centerMode: true,
          variableWidth: true,
      });
    });
</script>
```

The HTML portion is:

```
  <section class="section">
    <div class="swiper-container swiper-slider swiper-custom" data-height="35.10416666666667%" data-min-height="375px" data-index-bullet="false" data-slide-effect="swipe" data-autoplay="5000">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper swiper-wrapper-custom">
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-slide-bg="images/ergfer1.jpg">
          <div class="swiper-slide-caption">
            <div class="container text-center">
              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-8 top">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-slide-bg="images/gdrger.jpg">
          <div class="swiper-slide-caption">
            <div class="container text-center">
              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-8 top">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Is there a way to find out why my custom script is not active? The arrows are also not showing up. For anything HTML and CSS I use the Inspector of Firefox, but here I'm really stumped.

Comment: Are you seeing any JavaScript errors in your console?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you could include in your question the portion of your HTML that includes the elements of your slideshow (e.g. `.swiper-slide`).

Comment: You can definitely run into issues if the slick.js library is being included twice on your page.

Comment: @EdLucas I added the HTML portion  thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to consider:

1) When using slick.js, it is customary to add it to the element which is the parent of a set of elements which are then converted into slides. For example:

```
<div id="slide-wrapper">
    <div class="my-slide">...</div>
    <div class="my-slide">...</div>
    <div class="my-slide">...</div>
</div>

$('.slide-wrapper').slick({
    ...
});
```

In your case, that would mean adding Slick to `swiper-wrapper`:

```
$('.swiper-wrapper').slick({
    ...
});
```

2) More likely the problem is that you have a conflict with the setup of a different slide show library altogether, Swiper.js (https://swiperjs.com/api/), which uses classes like `swiper-container`, `swiper-wrapper` and `swiper-slide`. To implement that slideshow, you would have to include that library on your page and initialize the slideshow with something like:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    speed: 400,
    spaceBetween: 100
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ed. Indeed a complex issue, with the CSS declarations having the same name between the two competing systems and I don't think it'd be easy to clear a stylesheet from all the related bits of code. I'll take another approach thanks!